# I want to get values from one table to another and insert some form values how?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to add some data to mysql table from another mysql table and at the same time i want to add some form $_POST values to the same table in the same row.

Note : IM NEW TO PHP AND MYSQLI

Basically im looking for the correct syntax, please do help me and thanks in advance.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['ask'])) {

require('includes/connection.php');

$problem = $_POST['problem'];
$expecting = $_POST['expecting'];

//SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email' AND 

$string = "INSERT INTO ask(users_id,username,email,age,sex,problem,expecting) SELECT id,username,email,age,sex FROM users AND VALUES('$problem','$expecting') WHERE users.email = '$_SESSION[email]'";

$query = mysqli_query($dbc,$string);

if($query) {

    echo 'yes';

} else {

    echo 'something is wrong' . $query . mysqli_error();

}

}

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

</head>

<body>

    <div class="ask">

    <h1>Ask</h1>

    <form method="post" action="logged.php">

        <p><label>Problem: </label><input type="text" name="problem" value="<?php if(isset($problem)) { echo $problem; } ?>"></p>
        <p><label>Expecting: </label><input type="text" name="expecting" value="<?php if(isset($expecting)){ echo $expecting; } ?>"></p>
        <p><input type="submit" name="ask" value="Ask"></p>

    </form>

    </div>
    <form method="post" action="logged.php">

        <input type="submit" name="logout" value="Logout">

    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: and `mysqli_error()` said? or does it ever make it that far?

Comment: yes it said  Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\second\logged.php on line 95

Comment: well there you go; you're not getting the *real* error as to why your code failed. Look that up on Google and you'll know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is wrong database design. Instead of duplicating user's data in the questions table, you have only to *link it*. Read up on database normalization, and change your `ask` table by removing `username,email,age,sex` fields.

Then get user_id from users table with SELECT query.

Then run a conventional INSERT query

```
INSERT INTO ask(users_id,problem,expecting)
```

Note that you have to use prepared statements for database interactions.

Comment: if i want to do in this way, may i know the rite syntax, because im learning php, i need help from masters in php like you.